# Powershell command not working as expected

Tags: powershell, scripting

If I run the following command

```
Get-UserProfile
```

it will pull a list of the profiles on the local computer.

But if I try

```
Get-UserProfile -ComputerName Device1
```

I get this error even though this is the proper syntax

***Get-UserProfile : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ComputerName'.***

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. As the error indicates, there's no parameter of `-ComputerName`

Comment: That is exactly where the issue lies. the documentation for the Module clearly states that the Syntax to get profiles from remote Computers is Get-UserProfile -Computername Device1, Device2, Device3.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation and/or detail how you installed the module in question?

Comment: link: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-UserProfile/1.0.7/Content/Get-UserProfile.psm1 install with PS command: Install-Module -Name UserProfile

Answer (score 0):

The [`Get-UserProfile` module you to link to](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-UserProfile) is *not* the [`UserProfile` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/UserProfile) that you actually installed.

Only the former's `Get-UserProfile` command has a `-ComputerName` parameter.

Note that the `Get-UserProfile` module is *no longer listed* in the PowerShell Gallery, suggesting that it is no longer supported. In practice, this means that you can no longer discover it by search and you can no longer install it with [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module):

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the module is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

However, you're free to *manually download* the module.